# cakePHP - Managing a database CakeSessions

Tags: database, session, cakephp

After saving the session of the app in the database, I could see that the data is saved in json, if I remember correctly, but how to manage them, log out someone and / or modify the duration of the session by the database administrator or panel too?

I would like to have full control of data, but can not find anything on the internet, or even in Portuguese and English .... : (

cake_sessions table:

Config|a:3:{s:9:"userAgent";s:32:"9434032bcf68694ecc5837e4fde29390";s:4:"time";i:1311942893;s:7:"timeout";i:10;}Message|a:0:{}Auth|a:1:{s:8:"is_admin";s:1:"1";s:6:"active";s:1:"1";s:14:"room_connected";s:1:"0";}}Permissions|a:2:{i:0;s:12:"users:logout";i:1;s:1:"*";}

How to use a Custom Session setup with Database Storage

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/PHPdiddy/2010/08/29/how-to-use-a-custom-session-setup-with-database-storage

It should help a lot, but for those who still know how to use it, does not explain much ... = /

Answer (score 1):

It's not json, it's called `serialize()`'d

You should be able to turn the data back into variables with [`unserialize();`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)