# cakePHP 2.1 createing a custom session handler

Tags: session, cakephp, serialization

Using cakePHP 2.1, I want to write a custom session handler to perform extra cleanup upon destroy() and gc(), plus I want sessions to persist in a database. I'm following the example in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html , so I've defined:

```
class CustomSession extends DatabaseSession implements CakeSessionHandlerInterface { ...
```

The extra cleanup I need to do depends on a session variable which I want to obtain from the data field of the cake_sessions table in the database. I understand from [cakePHP - Managing a database CakeSessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869126/cakephp-managing-a-database-cakesessions) that this data is the result of the PHP serial() function and I can use unserial() to get an object of the previously serialized data. However, using unserial() on data from cake_sessions always results in:

```
Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 159 byte
```

Outside of cakePHP, I've written the following

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM testdb.cake_sessions WHERE id = 'b5d4vc0143ruh420hmkvl7s722'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($row['data']) . '</pre>';
$session_vars = unserialize($row['data']);
echo '<pre>' . $session_vars . '</pre>';
```

The above prints the serialized data field from cake_sessions table, but not the unserialized object due to the previously described error. Some forum posts mention that this is a MySQL issue and to use blob instead of text as the type of the data field, but this made no difference.

A test example of the data field obtained from cake_sessions is:

```
    Config|a:3{s:9:"userAgent";s:32:"d7e7d243e8bfaf713b70bde2a6ef1c18";s:4:"time";i:1341540422;s:9:"countdown";i:10;}Customer|a:2:{s:4:"cart";i:1;s:4:"test";i:2;}
```

The meaning of the serialization is obvious, so I could hand parse it, but I'd rather not.

Why isn't unserial() working and/or is there an existing PHP function to unserialize the data that will work?